# bash: No such file or directory when running a dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a container from a `dockerfile` and a `docker-compose` file which look like this -

`docker-compose.yml`

```
build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      target: go-container
    entrypoint: bash -c "./main"
```

the `Dockerfile` looks like this -

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.17
FROM golang:$GO_VERSION as go-container
ENV GOPATH /gopath
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /gopath/src/project

ADD go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download -x
RUN go build -o main cmd/main.go


FROM scratch as another_container
COPY --from=go-container /gopath/src/project/main .
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

On running the `docker-compose`, I get an error like this -

```
bash: line 1: ./main: No such file or directory
ERROR: 127
```

What is happening here? I don't know how to debug it so any help is appreciated!

Comment: `bash -c "./main"`? Why have the `bash -c` (which requires your container to have bash in it) and not just make `main` your entrypoint on its own?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I removed the `entrypoint: bash -c "./main"` from my `docker-compose` and it created container successfully

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM scratch as another_container
```

You're using a FROM statement, which replaces the current container with a new container based on an image. In this case, you're doing it `FROM scratch`, which is a container with nothing in it.

Since you didn't use `COPY --from` to copy the compiled file from the previous stage, the file `./main` is missing, so your application won't work.

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages) for a multistage Go build example.

Comment: Can you please check my updated dockerfile command in the post? I have actually used the `Copy --from` command

Comment: `COPY --from` must come after `FROM`. See the example I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Docker `scratch` doesn't have binaries such as `bash`, basically it's an empty context. The `FROM scratch as another_container` instruction then removes previous layers; in this case `./main` file is excluded.

You could use another minimal image, ie `FROM busybox as another_container`, to execute the `./main` binary.

ie:

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.17
FROM golang:$GO_VERSION as go-container
ADD go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download -x
RUN go build -o main cmd/main.go
FROM busybox as another_container
COPY --from=go-container ./main /main
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

Full example:

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: go-container
    entrypoint: bash -c "./main"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.17
FROM golang:$GO_VERSION as go-container
ENV GOPATH /gopath
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /gopath/src/project

ADD go.mod go.sum main.go ./
RUN go mod download -x
RUN go build -o main main.go

FROM busybox as another_container
COPY --from=go-container /gopath/src/project/main .

ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Created with vim-go")
}
```

Execute with: `docker compose up`

```bash
docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network delete_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container delete-web-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to delete-web-1
delete-web-1  | vim-go
delete-web-1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated dockerfile command in the post? I have actually used the Copy --from command

Comment: I updated my answer with full exampler.